# Concatenating two images in opengl

Tags: image, opengl, camera

I'm developing a little videogame in which I have an infinite background image which moves horizontally. The image obviously is not infinite, it just finishes the same way it starts, so if I concatenate the image with itself, it seems is infinite.

The problem I'm having is that in the place where the two images join, a vertical black line appear. Looks like is not joining them in the exact position and I can see the black background.

I thought it was because the width of the images were not integers, but even if I superimpose one image over the other, the black vertical line still appear.

Any tips please?

Comment: You have to provide more information. Generally, OpenGL can do this automatically via GL_REPEAT, but you seem to be doing something different. E.g., are you rendering quads with the image on them?

Comment: I'm just render a large horizontal image. When it is going to finish, I draw it again at the end.

Comment: What does "I'm just render a large horizontal image" mean? How are you rendering it? Are you apply the image as a texture to a quad? Have you verified in an image processing program that there's really no black line in the input image?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called tiling. The image should be inherently 'tile-able'. To do this, put two copies of the image side by side, edges flush with each other and see if they are seamless.

Now then, to make things work in OpenGL, the simplest way might to make the quad (i.e. the mesh) holding your background pretty large and map this texture to a small part of this mesh (so that the image itself doesn't look stretched). Use the GL_REPEAT flag when texture mapping so the image is tiled across the entire large quad.